# Getting gvim to automatically translate a cygwin path

Tags: cygwin, vim

I love cygwin and the native windows version of gvim and I use them together all the time.  The only problem I have is with cygwin path names.  Gvim for windows doesn't understand them so I have to resort to typing things like:

```
gvim `cygpath -wa ~/scripts/myscript.pl`
```

Which is annoying!

I was wondering if there's a neat way of using autocmds to detect if a cygwin path has been provided and, if so, convert it to a windows path on the FileReadPre event.  Does anyone know if/how this can be acomplished?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There exist several solutions (see vim.wikia.com, cygwin category).

I'm maintaining the more flexible one: [cyg-wrapper.sh](http://hermitte.free.fr/cygwin/#Win32) (flexible in the sense it knows that (vim) flags are not pathnames, and it can even be told that "binary" flags like -c expect another argument that is not a pathname, and in the sense that it is not vim specific)

Regarding the invocation of cygwin executables from win32-vim, you won't have any troubles ... as long as the executable won't return pathnames expressed in *nix format. 
For all compilation related executables (gcc/make/doxygen/...) I also have a solution. In the past it was a simple standalone perl script (still available on vim.org). Now I have a full solution that does other compilation related stuff: [BuildToolsWrapper](http://code.google.com/p/lh-vim/source/browse/#svn/BTW/trunk) (that requires lh-vim-lib on the same site)

Regarding things like `:e /etc/hosts`, I have no solutions. A long time ago, I've tried to play with FileReadPre & co, but I gave up along the way, and I don't remember why ^^'.

Comment: Thanks for this, it works particularly nicely when combined with an alias in .bashrc.  I.e.:

alias gvim='cyg-wrapper.sh gvim'

Allows me to type:

gvim ~/scripts/myscript.sh

Just nicely :-)

Comment: This... is awesome! I've been looking for something like this for a while, I can't stand the GTK gVim on cygwin. ClearType is soooo much better.

Comment: I have another question about cyg-wrapper - care to chime in? http://superuser.com/questions/298792/how-to-use-cyg-wrapper-to-fork-a-new-tab-in-win32-gvim/

Comment: Thanks for the wonderful `cyg-wrapper`; it deserves to be better known.